# Умножить результат запроса из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть результат суммы из колонок:

```
$result_t = mysqli_query($con, "select sum( i_01_00 + . . .  + i_23_59) as my_big_sum from my_table where my_date = '$curDate'");
```

Вывод в таблице в HTML `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_t);`

Задача: полученую сумму умножить и получить еще одну.
Пытался решить как:

```
$summ = $row['my_big_summ'] * 2;
```

Но, конечно же, ошибка.
`Notice: Undefined index: my_big_summ in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final2\internet_1_day.php on line 67` - ошибка на `$summ`.

Как решить?

Comment: А вы ошибки проверяете? У вас может в запросе ошибка? Но здесь, правда, другое: `my_big_summ` != `my_big_sum`. Сделали бы дамп $row - увидели бы. Учитесь отлаживать код )

Comment: Ворон - с выводом $row - нет проблем. Мне нужно умножить результат и вывести его.
echo "<table border = '1' width = '800'>
  <tr>
   <td width=200><h3><p class='sansserif'>Total spend</p></h3></td>
   <td width=200>" . $row['my_big_sum'] . " - Gb</td>
   <td width=200>Summ</td>
   <td width=200>". $summ ."</td>
  </tr>";
  echo "</table>";

Смотри результат вывода:

http://s019.radikal.ru/i621/1503/9f/c411447428c3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Используйте второй параметр для функции `mysqli_fetch_array`.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_t, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Когда без параметра, тогда возможны сразу оба варианта, т.е. ваш пример ничего для автора не изменит.

Я же написал ошибку: my_big_summ (в массиве) != my_big_sum (в запросе). Т.е.  про my_big_summ PHP ничего не знает, потому и ругается.

Надо убрать лишнюю букву

Comment: Все идеально!
Все верно!
Лишняя буква, портила результат.
Спасибо за внимательность и помощь.